# Apache rule based on http status and on response status

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to create an apache rule based on the user agent AND on the http response.

For example, I want a rule that says: *if user-agent=test and the status of the request based on this user agent=503, redirect the request to /home*

[On the documentation page,](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) I found a variable for based on the user agent(`HTTP_USER_AGENT`), but nothing for the http status.
Is that possible?

Comment: It depends how the 503 is being triggered. How is the 503 being triggered? You can't arbitrarily check the HTTP response status in Apache if, for instance, this is being set by your application (not Apache). (Although you don't necessarily need to check the actual response code if you know what would trigger that response to begin with.)

Comment: First the pasge is loaded, then on this page, differents requests will be done (executed by this specific user agent)

Comment: But how exactly are you setting the 503 response status in the first place? You can detect the status code if you are setting this in Apache (which would be expected for a 503), but from your comment this may not be the case (although it is not clear)?

Comment: I do not want to set the http status, I want to check what is the result (http status) of these queries.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following, to define a custom 503 "error document" when a request with the `User-Agent` "test" is sent:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'test'">
    ErrorDocument 503 https://example.com/home
</If>
```

When an absolute URL is used in the `ErrorDocument` directive, it will trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect to that URL should the stated HTTP response status be triggered by Apache.

So, the above will issue an external redirect to `/home` when a request with `User-Agent` "test" triggers a 503 response in Apache.

This will need to be defined in the main server config (not `.htaccess`) to stand a chance of catching an arbitrary 503 generated by the server. Although it is questionable whether this would catch such an "unexpected" error since a 503 - if triggered by the server itself - is a rather serious/fatal error. Ordinarily, a 503 is a *controlled* response for when the application goes into "maintenance mode". In this scenario, you would arguably handle this differently.

Alternatively, the `REDIRECT_STATUS` *environment variable* holds the HTTP response status code so you could do something like the following using mod_rewrite to *override* the `ErrorDocument` and trigger a 302 redirect to `/home`:

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =503
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=test"
RewriteRule ^ /home [R=302,L]
```

If the 503 is triggered by the application itself (eg. in PHP) then this will not be caught by the above rule(s).

Answer (score -1):

[The documentation page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) mentions the following environment variables:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT
HTTP_COOKIE
HTTP_FORWARDED
HTTP_HOST
HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION
HTTP_REFERER
HTTP_USER_AGENT
AUTH_TYPE
CONN_REMOTE_ADDR
CONTEXT_PREFIX
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT
IPV6
PATH_INFO
QUERY_STRING
REMOTE_ADDR
REMOTE_HOST
REMOTE_IDENT
REMOTE_PORT
REMOTE_USER
REQUEST_METHOD
SCRIPT_FILENAME
DOCUMENT_ROOT
SCRIPT_GROUP
SCRIPT_USER
SERVER_ADDR
SERVER_ADMIN
SERVER_NAME
SERVER_PORT
SERVER_PROTOCOL
SERVER_SOFTWARE
TIME_YEAR
TIME_MON
TIME_DAY
TIME_HOUR
TIME_MIN
TIME_SEC
TIME_WDAY
TIME
API_VERSION
CONN_REMOTE_ADDR
HTTPS
IS_SUBREQ
REMOTE_ADDR
REQUEST_FILENAME
REQUEST_SCHEME
REQUEST_URI
THE_REQUEST
```

Sadly, I am unable to find any variables that show the HTTP status.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. Does that mean that I am at a dead end?

Comment: @Warok Yes. But not fully, as you can still edit the source code of Apache HTTP Server itself, and add the redirection there. (But you would need knowledge of C, and Apache HTTP Server itself)